# Reading a set of coordinates from a file in python

Tags: python

im lookig for a way to take a file with the following information:

```
(200,500)
(300,100)
(450,150)
(520,480)
```

and putting it in a list like this one:

```
[(200, 500), (300, 100), (450, 150), (520, 480)]
```

I tried this:

```
lineas = open("texto.txt").readlines()
print(lineas)
```

But i get the following:

```
['(200,500)\n', '(300,100)\n', '(450,150)\n', '(520,480)']
```

Does anyone knows how i could fix the list so its like the one i want?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse the tuples.

```
import ast

with open("texto.txt") as f:
    lines = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in f]
```